# AT Command CMGR - Missing Result Code

Tags: at-command, modem, gprs

I am sending e.g. **AT+CMGR=1** to a Wavecom GSM Modem. After this i got the message like:

> +CMGR: "REC UNREAD","+85291234567",,"07/02/18,00:05:10+32"
>   It is easy to read text messages via AT commands.

But there is no Result Codes at the end, after the message text. If successful there should be **OK** otherwise I miss the **ERROR** code.

Now my question: How could I enable the result code or is perhaps the modem firmware broken ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two AT commands that control the presentation of final result codes, defined in the [V.250 specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en). `ATV` for text or numeric, and `ATQ` for suppression:

> 6.2.5  Result code suppression
>
> Parameter
>
> Q`[<value>]`
>
> Description
>
> The setting of this parameter determines whether or not the DCE transmits result codes to the DTE. When result codes are being
> suppressed, no portion of any intermediate, final, or unsolicited
> result code – header, result text, line terminator, or trailer – is
> transmitted. Information text transmitted in response to commands is
> not affected by the setting of this parameter.

So if ATQ is set to 1, then the modem should behave like you describe, although that is not in any way tied to just AT+CMGR, it should then apply to all commands. If this only occurs with AT+CMGR, then it is a firmware bug.

Comment: Thx for answer. I am sending the ATQ0 command to the modem and only the parameter AT+CMGR=X (X for a number) is working without OK reponse. So i will look for a firmware update.